# Importing from a function within a function in Python

Tags: python, function, variables

I have a file (test.py):

```
def main():
    def hello():
        x = 10
```

Then I have another file (test2.py):

```
from test import *
print(main.hello.x)
```

Now I know that `print(main.hello.x)` won't work but I want something like that.

I want to access a variable inside another file that is in a nested function.

How can I do that?

Comment: perhaps you could post your exact code, doing so could make it easier to provide alternative methods to achieving what you would like to achieve

Comment: `hello` isn't created until `main` is called, so it doesn't actually exist yet. It seems to me like you want `main` to be a class instead.

Comment: my actual code is pretty big. do you still want it?

Comment: You can't, since `hello` doesn't exist until `main` is actually called (and, unless it's returned, will cease existing when `main` finishes).  Why do you want to do this instead of making a class or some other structure?

Comment: ya, I was thinking about creating a class as well.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), hence we would like to know the broader picture of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

This feels quite unpythonic, but this will work:

```
def main():
    def hello():
        hello.x = 10
        return hello
    main.hello = hello
    return main

print(main.hello.x) #returns 10
```

a more pythonic approach is to use a class.

Comment: yes, thank you, I am now using a class